# Looking for solution to add double quotes in field which has commas in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016, ssis-expressions

I have a field called something like TYPE & the values are variant in it. I want the SSIS to export the result to CSV & while exporting, if it finds the , in column TYPE only that line/value should be double quoted.
Eg:

TYPE 
Begin Bag 1,000 mL
Miscellaneous 20ml
Final 2,000 mL
Begin Bag 1 mL

the result should be (in the csv format exported):
TYPE
"Begin Bag 1,000 mL",
Miscellaneous 20ml,
"Final 2,000 mL",
Begin Bag 1 mL

I tried using the Derived column "\""+ TYPE +"\"" but that just adds Double quotes to every value for column TYPE.

Please help!

THanks,
Atulya

Comment: See [this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) from the Help Center to merge your two accounts ("Atulya" and "atulya dharmaraj"). Then, you'll be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use SSIS `CASE` syntax in your derived column node as follows:

```
FINDSTRING(TextLine,",",1) > 0 ? "\"" + TextLine + "\"" : TextLine
```

The expression basically says - if a comma is found in TextLine, THEN wrap it in double quotes ELSE just keep Textline

[image]